# I want to put validation for the prime Number Program

Tags: javascript

If the user enters nothing in the prompt box then also it is showing "The num is prime", I have put validation below. Also if I enter "1" in prompt box, it is still showing "The num is prime".

```
    var Num = prompt("Enter the Number");

    var flag = 0;

   if (isNaN(Num)) {
        alert("please enter valid number");
    }

    for (var i = 2; i < Num; i++) {
        if (Num % 2 === 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag === 0) {
        alert("The num is prime");
    } 
    else if (flag === 1) {
        alert("The num is not prime");
    }
```

Comment: Put the if statement for flag = 0 and flag = 1 at the top before the loop.

Comment: Learn to properly indent your code. It makes the flow of execution much more clear. Also, you're misusing `IsNan` - it doesn't mean *the user didn't enter a number*.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what your question is...

Comment: Hi Ajay, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, the question as posted is not structured in a way that invites well-formed answers.  Please review [ask] - remember, clear, high-quality questions are required for high quality answers.  Perhaps review the link and then edit this for clarity.  Welcome again, and happy coding!

Comment: Will improve it, as this was my first question on stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Annoyingly, `isNaN("")` returns false, as if `""` were a number. To fix the problem with the empty prompt, you're gonna need to check that `Num.length > 0`</strike>

The `isNaN` function is not intended to be used to check whether or not something can be interpreted as a number. It's intended to check if the provided value is the specific `NaN` value. My suggestion would be to attempt to convert the prompted string into a number and see if that conversion was successful.

```
var Num = parseInt(prompt("Enter the Number"), 10);
if(Number.isNaN(Num)) {
    alert("please enter valid number");
}
```

Please note: this will not ensure that all provided values will be valid. For example, `parseInt("ABC123")` will return `NaN` as expected, but `parseInt("123ABC")` will return `123` and ignore the subsequent "ABC".

Regarding the issue with 1s, the code you have provided appears to mark all odd numbers as prime. Assuming you have written the part that determines whether or not an odd number is prime, you could have a special case to say "if the number is 1, it's not prime." That's because for many purposes, 1 acts like a prime number. Obviously, it's not the most elegant solution, but... it works.

Comment: Whoever's downvoting, would you mind telling me what I can improve?

Comment: `isNaN` isn't evaluating if something is or is not a number, it is evaluating if something is the value `NaN`.

Comment: *For some odd reason* No, it's not an odd reason. You (and the poster) need to learn what NaN means. It does **not** mean *the user didn't input a numeric digit*. There's nothing *odd*.

Comment: @AlexanderNied That is incorrect. Evaluate `isNaN("aaa")` and you will see that it returns true, meaning it counts "aaa" as a NaN value.

Comment: @AlexanderNied @Ken White You are thinking of `Number.isNaN`, which is a different function.

Comment: @EKW - It is a different function with slightly different behavior, but the [purpose is still the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN): "The `isNaN()` function determines whether a value is `NaN` or not. Note: coercion inside the `isNaN` function has interesting rules; you may alternatively want to use `Number.isNaN()`, as defined in ECMAScript 2015."

Comment: @AlexanderNied regardless of the purpose of the function, the defined behavior of the `isNaN` function means that (unlike `Number.isNaN`), it will attempt to coerce the passed value into a number before checking if it's NaN. Because a non-number string becomes NaN if coercion is attempted, `isNaN` will return true for non-number strings... except for empty strings

Comment: @EKW: I have checked the condition (Num.length > 0) in for loop but still it is not working.

Comment: @EKW - I never claimed that wasn't the case, I was responding to this from your answer: **'For some annoying reason, isNaN("") returns false, as if "" were a number.'** This seems to suggest you think `isNaN` is for evaluating if something is or is not a number.

Comment: Attempting to justify misuse of `IsNaN` is a waste of time. It's not the appropriate means for determining whether a numeric digit was input. No matter how hard you argue that a hammer is the proper tool for everything, it's not what you use to replace a broken window pane. NaN has a specific meaning, and trying to pretend it means something else is silly. So is *Please tell me what's wrong with my question* and then objecting when everyone provides facts to explain what's wrong.

Comment: I agree. It's a bad practice. I wouldn't do it in *my* code, but... this isn't my code. I'm not trying to justify it. I'm just saying, it *does* work for... most of OP's purposes. It's a hammer when OP needs a mallet.

Comment: I apologize for objecting. I misunderstood your complaint. I thought you were saying it behaved differently than I described. I didn't realize you were speaking solely in terms of the function's intention.

Comment: Not a *hammer vs. mallet*. More of a *hammer vs. glass cutter*. Wrong tool is wrong tool, and a misuse of a function is a misuse of a function.

Comment: Just realized in all of this we haven't indicated to OP the _proper_ way to do this: @AjayMalhotra - the proper way to evaluate if something is a number is `typeof myVar === "number"`.  Now it is worth noting that there are edgy cases for this-- for instance `typeof NaN` evaluates to "number" as well.  But only if you are concerned about the presence of `NaN` do you have to check for this, which you can do by leveraging `Number.isNaN` or `isNaN`.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Considering the number is in string form, `typeof Num === "number"` will always return false.

Comment: @EKW - yeah, you're right-- for OP's purpose, he'd want to attempt a controlled way to parse it to a number first before evaluating if it was a proper number that met his requirements.

Comment: This debate is distracting from the point, which is that the post needs some improvement before an attempt is made to answer it. @AlexanderNied: As your comment to the OP indicates, the question is unclear, which means that any attempt to answer it is premature.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your point. Sorry for the argument.